# Regarding Choice in fields outside set theory.

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

When authors say stuff like

> The equivalence of continuity and sequential continuity in metric spaces uses(/requires) some version of the axiom of choice.

Are they assuming that we are working inside a model of $\sf ZFC$ or something like that?

I'm asking this mostly because of a proof I read by Rudin of that fact, using the axiom of choice, but not saying so explicitly. If everything is left implicit, is it standard to assume that we're working with $\sf ZFC$ and/or a model of it?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Longer answer: from my experience, everything that uses nothing beyond axiom of dependent choice is kept implicit, because it's very easy to just hide DC inside an inductive construction.

Comment: @Arthur I'm not so sure about that. There are routine tasks in analysis which require more than dependent choice. For example, in general we need Zorn's lemma to get the full set of eigenvectors of certain operators. For another example, we assemble the Vitali set, i.e. $[0,1]/(\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1])$, using choice, which amounts to extracting an element from the Cartesian product of uncountably many disjoint, countably infinite sets. These are tricky, and it is probably not clear to everyone that you can do this without contradiction.

Comment: (Cont.) By contrast, as Wojowu said, it is somehow "obvious" that dependent choice is legitimate, because one can essentially frame its use as an inductive construction. To be sure, I don't think everyone needs to learn axiomatic set theory, but at the same time choice is a sufficiently delicate matter that mathematicians should probably at least be aware of it even if they don't understand everything about it.

Comment: @Ian I meant to say "except for AC" in there somewhere. Naïve set theory, together with "Russel's paradox is resolved down there somewhere, and we don't care much about how" and being conscious of the axiom of choice is the feeling I've gotten from most textbooks.

Comment: In my experience the axiom of choice is generally taken for granted. Frankly, I see no real need for most mathematicians even to be aware of it save as a bit of general mathematical culture.

Comment: @Arthur Then I agree with you. The rest of ZFC, for non-logicians, basically says "these things (e.g. equality) are defined the way you would expect" and "by assuming these things we keep things from breaking in any obvious way without being too restrictive".

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering your last question.

Upon more than century's evidence, it is scientifically proved that almost all correct mathematics can be formulated in ZFC, with eventually additional (explicitly quoted) axioms.

More precisely: Every mathematical theorem can be translated (at least theoretically) into a first order statement in the language $\{\in\}$, and  its *mathematical* proof  into a proof in first order logic, where axioms are taken from the infinite list ZFC. It might be the case that you need some **extra** power to do some calculation; this might be a [sufficiently big universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory), or that there are [few elements in some set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis), or that [some subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_projective_determinacy) of the real line is Lebesgue measurable. Any of these additional assumptions (that is, anything outside ZFC) must be explicitely quoted somewhere in your proof. A theorem proved using assumptions outside ZFC is only *conditionally proved* (similarly as when you prove something under the assumption of the Riemann Hypothesis).

On the contrary, you do not need to ask for permission before using anything *on* the list (and AC is listed among ZFC axioms).